# How to "call" the value from a SQL database?

Tags: c#, sql, database, call

I have a registration and login system, and I need to call the name variable from the SQL database. I need a welcome message.

```
label2.Text = "Welcome!" + nameFromDatabase;
```

How I can retrieve the name value from the database?

Comment: Post your tried code

Comment: I just need a code what is call the value from the sql database for the label message

Comment: @CoopCky: i have posted a sample code for your reference. As we don't know which way you are doing. You can try the code below.

Comment: As @stack has mentioned you can get the user name from session variable. Since user name is entered at the time of login you can use that name. If you still want to pull from data base then you will need to use connection, command, data reader object and sql query something like "select * from table where username='<username>'".

Answer (score 0):

If you use `ASP.NET membership` on your site, then you can display the current user `username` as user's is logged in. See the below code:-

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // First find if user is logged in
    if (Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        // Finds user name and says Welcome 
        lblWelcome.Text = "Welcome " + Context.User.Identity.Name;
    }
    else
    {
        // It is anonymous user, say Welcome  to guest
        lblWelcome.Text = "Welcome guest";
    }
}
```

Other way is to bring the Username in the `Session` and display it by using label

```
lblWelcome.Text = "Welcome " + Session["UserName"].ToString();
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i did it :)

Comment: If this worked for you, mark the tick and accept it as an answer. It would help for the future reader. Thanks.